# Loop and Time Delay

Tags: vb.net, loops, wait

I've created a program which loads a webpage.
Then I programmed 3 buttons which perform operations on the website. This functions fine.

But now I want to implement a button which will click Button1 one time, then it should wait 5 sec and then a loop should start and hit Button2 10 times. After this, the whole process should start again. The program is kind of a bot.

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Call Button1_Click(sender, e)
    Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
End Sub
```

`Application.Wait` doesn't function because `Application` is not a member of `System.Windows` Forms.

How can I implement the delay? How can I implement the loop?

Comment: I believe you are working in vb.net not vba. If so, try this: `Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)`

Comment: Ou yess thank you :)

Comment: But i got now another problem.

Comment: Call Button1_Click(sender, e)
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
        Call Button2_Click(sender, e)

My idea was that first the button1 clicked. In this 5 sec time the new website could be load.
And then the the button2 make another action on thie new loaded website.

But with this code, it doesnt function. The first website stays ther without an action. It seems that both button be clicked after 5 sec, but without loading the new site. Can you please help me ? :)

Comment: why would you want the `Button2` to be clicked 10 times? or you mean click `button1` once and then click `button2` after 5 seconds and repeat every 5 seconds?

Comment: Yes exactly. Press Button1. And after 5sec Button2 and then after 5sec press Button 2 again, etc....

Comment: Because i want that in thies time, the implemented browser can load teh next page, after the click of the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments, Threading.Thread.Sleep() gives you a problem that the website isn't loaded. The problem is that Threading.Thread.Sleep() stops your whole program from executing code as it freezes it. Here is how to make your program wait for some time.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Async Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        MessageBox.Show("Commands before waiting")
        Await Wait(5000)
        MessageBox.Show("Commands after waiting")
    End Sub

    Private Async Function Wait(ByVal ms As Integer) As Task
        Await Task.Delay(ms)
    End Function

End Class
```

Just replace the MessageBox(s) with the commands you need before and after waiting.

Note: This requires .NET Framework 4.5 or higher

**UPDATE based on Fabio comment**:

It can directly be done without need of Wait method like this:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Async Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        MessageBox.Show("Commands before waiting")
        Await Task.Delay(5000)
        MessageBox.Show("Commands after waiting")
    End Sub

End Class
```

This also can be used in .NET framework 3.5 or higher but it needs some libraries which can be downloaded from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async)

Comment: I think there no need for `Wait` method, you can use `Task.Delay` as well.

Comment: `Async-Await` approach can be used in .NET 3.5 and 4.0 as well. You only need to add some dependencies(libraries) for supporting those features.

Comment: @Fabio Thanks for your useful information ^_^
May I ask what are the libraries needed for achieve that in .NET 4.0? It would be very useful to me :)

Comment: [https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async)